# How to deprecate an Array type declaration in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, deprecated

I need to mark as **deprecated** an array type declaration (well, actually more than just one), in order to help migrate our code to the more advanced and flexible `TArray<T>` generic type.

I've tried this:

```
type
  TArrayChars = array of Char deprecated;
```

but I got a compilation error: `E2029 ';' expected but identifier 'deprecated' found`

The same works if the declared type isn't an array, for example:

```
type
  TFieldChars = set of Char deprecated;
```

Note that this should be feasible by design.

What am I missing?

---

This seems to be a bug in Delphi (at least 10.1 Berlin and 10.2 Tokyo).

My accepted answer proposes a neat **workaround**, that is:

```
type
  TArrayCharsOld = array of Char;
  TArrayChars    = TArrayCharsOld deprecated;
```

I'll file a bug report to Embarcadero.

---

This is the Embarcadero QC issue I've submitted:
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18316

Comment: You should file a bug report.

Comment: @William No, it's not a duplicate of that question, here I'm talking of declaring a TYPE as deprecated, something that should be possible reading the docs. Properties are another story, and not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @Bozzy but the answer of the linked question, can be used for your issue.

Comment: @William How? The documentation that is linked there states that the code in the question should compile.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it may be a delphi bug.

Comment: @William Yes I think it's a delphi bug. This doesn't mean all questions about delphi bugs are duplicates ;) Anyway, my question is about something that should be feasible by design, while the other asks for something not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @William Indeed. But not a dupe of that question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My mistake. In fact, all that you can do is report do embarcadero, meanwhile the bug is not solved you can write a comment saying that is deprecated.

Comment: @William Er, the point of marking deprecated is so that the compiler generates a warning for every use of that symbol.

Comment: Writing a comment could be useful, but not even close to the usefulness of a hint directive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way around it (at least in 10.1 Berlin).

```
type
  TArrayCharsOld = array of Char;
  TArrayChars = TArrayCharsOld deprecated;
```

compiles.

Comment: Yeah, that will get it done, crafty too. I tried that, saw it compiled, but did not make the leap to arrange the alias such that the deprecated type was the one used by the rest of the code. Nice work.

Comment: Yes it works! Actually I get **two** identical warnings for each use of the deprecated type! Maybe this is another bug?

Comment: Yes, I got two warnings too.

Comment: Maybe this will strengthen the feeling of something to get rid of!

Comment: I assume that the fact that you can't deprecate the array declaration directly is a bug, and not "as designed". The fact that you get two warnings now is probably related to that bug.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing much to say. Dynamic array type declarations cannot be marked as deprecated.

I would consider this to be a defect. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements) says:

> The 'hint' directives platform, deprecated, and library may be
>   appended to any declaration. These directives will produce warnings at
>   compile time. Hint directives can be applied to type declarations,
>   variable declarations, class, interface, and structure declarations,
>   field declarations within classes or records, procedure, function, and
>   method declarations, and unit declarations.

Your dynamic array type declaration meets the requirements listed here since it is a type declaration.

Comment: This is the kind of answer one would never hope to read. I'll file a bug report to Embarcadero.

Comment: Irrespective of the workaround, you should still file a bug report

Comment: Sure I'll do. Workarounds are not solutions.